# PHP Do not display variable if value in array does not exist

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question, but I've been stumped on how to prevent a value from repeating when it doesn't exist in an array. Here is an example of the array:

```
Array ( 
    [meta_id] => 995 
    [order_item_id] => 83 
    [meta_key] => Booking Date 
    [meta_value] => February 7, 2015 
) 
Array ( 
    [meta_id] => 996 
    [order_item_id] => 83 
    [meta_key] => Booking Time 
    [meta_value] => 7:00 am 
) 
Array ( 
    [meta_id] => 997 
    [order_item_id] => 83 
    [meta_key] => First Name - First Name 
    [meta_value] => Dan 
) 
Array ( 
    [meta_id] => 998 
    [order_item_id] => 83 
    [meta_key] => Church Information - Church Name 
    [meta_value] => Colonial Hills Baptist Church 
) 
Array ( 
    [meta_id] => 1010 
    [order_item_id] => 84 
    [meta_key] => Booking Date 
    [meta_value] => January 8, 2015 
) 
Array ( 
    [meta_id] => 1011 
    [order_item_id] => 84 
    [meta_key] => Booking Time 
    [meta_value] => 2:00 am 
) 
Array ( 
    [meta_id] => 1012 
    [order_item_id] => 84 
    [meta_key] => First Name - First Name 
    [meta_value] => Gary 
) 
Array ( 
    [meta_id] => 1013 
    [order_item_id] => 84 
    [meta_key] => Church Information - Church Name 
    [meta_value] => Victory Bible Church 
)
Array ( 
    [meta_id] => 973 
    [order_item_id] => 81 
    [meta_key] => Booking Date 
    [meta_value] => March 7, 2015 
) 
Array ( 
    [meta_id] => 974 
    [order_item_id] => 81 
    [meta_key] => Booking Time 
    [meta_value] => 3:00 am 
) 
Array ( 
    [meta_id] => 975 
    [order_item_id] => 81 
    [meta_key] => First Name - First Name 
    [meta_value] => Dan 
)
Array ( 
    [meta_id] => 925 
    [order_item_id] => 77 
    [meta_key] => Booking Date 
    [meta_value] => January 1, 2015 
) 
Array ( 
    [meta_id] => 926 
    [order_item_id] => 77 
    [meta_key] => Booking Time 
    [meta_value] => 10:00 am 
) 
Array ( 
    [meta_id] => 927 
    [order_item_id] => 77 
    [meta_key] => First Name - First Name 
    [meta_value] => Kent 
) 
...
```

You can see in these arrays that they are grouped by the order_item_id key. And you will also see that the arrays with order_item_id of 81 and 77 do not have the Church Information - Church Name meta_key and meta_value.

Here is the code to produce these arrays:

```
foreach( $order_items as $order_item ) {
                            $item_meta = $wpdb->get_results("
                                SELECT  *
                                FROM        {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta
                                WHERE   order_item_id = " . $order_item->order_item_id . "
                            ");

                            $meta_array = objectToArray( $item_meta );

                            foreach( $meta_array as $data ) {

                                    if( $data['meta_key'] == 'Booking Date' ) 
                                        $date = $data['meta_value'];
                                    if( $data['meta_key'] == 'Booking Time' )
                                        $time = $data['meta_value'];
                                    if( $data['meta_key'] == 'First Name - First Name' )
                                        $fname = $data['meta_value'];
                                    if( $data['meta_key'] == 'Church Information - Church Name' )
                                        $church = $data['meta_value'];
                                    if( $data['meta_key'] == 'Church Information - City' )
                                        $city = $data['meta_value'];
                                    if( $data['meta_key'] == 'Church Information - State' )
                                        $state = $data['meta_value'];
                            }

                            echo $fname . ', ' . $church . '<br>';

                        }
```

Here is the result:

```
Dan, Colonial Hills Baptist Church
Gary, Victory Bible Church
Dan, Victory Bible Church
Kent, Victory Bible Church
```

As you can see, the results for the $church variable are repeating and displaying in areas where that value doesn't exist. In the result above, only Gary should have the value "Victory Bible Church" associated with it.

Can someone help me resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to initialize the variable in the loop as otherwise the old value will be used and you have an `undefined variable` problem at the start if the first record does not have it set.

Comment: 2 ways: Preset all the variables (city, church etc) to empty string before all ifs, or use else statement to set them to empty string

Comment: Thanks @jeroen The answer below let me see what it means to initialize a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the variables at each cycle, as follows:

```
foreach( $order_items as $order_item ) {
    $item_meta = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT  *
        FROM        {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta
        WHERE   order_item_id = " . $order_item->order_item_id . "
    ");

    $meta_array = objectToArray( $item_meta );

    $date = "";
    $time = "";
    fname = "";
    $church = "";
    $city = "";
    $state = "";

    foreach( $meta_array as $data ) {

            if( $data['meta_key'] == 'Booking Date' ) 
                $date = $data['meta_value'];
            else if( $data['meta_key'] == 'Booking Time' )
                $time = $data['meta_value'];
            else if( $data['meta_key'] == 'First Name - First Name' )
                $fname = $data['meta_value'];
            else if( $data['meta_key'] == 'Church Information - Church Name' )
                $church = $data['meta_value'];
            else if( $data['meta_key'] == 'Church Information - City' )
                $city = $data['meta_value'];
            else if( $data['meta_key'] == 'Church Information - State' )
                $state = $data['meta_value'];
    }

    echo $fname . ', ' . $church . '<br>';

}
```

Comment: I'm working on custom code to display Booked Dates with special Data from the WooCommerce Bookings plugin for Wordpress. Since I'm new to PHP, I would like to see if you can review my code and check for inefficiencies: (http://pastebin.com/14QSSX9m). This code could eventually query up to 8700 orders. The result can be see here: (http://www.pray2015.com/men/)